# Need help aligning 3 images using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have been working on a site recently and I am having trouble trying to align 3 different sized images across the page, I desperately need some help with this issue.
Here is my CSS code:

```
img .gameimages {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<img src="Images/LoadingE.png"> 
<p class="gameimages" style="clear: both; text-align: centre;">We have an animated loading screen!</p>
<img src="Images/GameE.png">
<p class="gameimages" style="clear: both; text-align: centre;">We have an interactive main menu!</p>
<img src="Images/player.png">
<p class="gameimages" style="clear: both; text-align: centre;">This is our amazing player!</p>
```

Comment: Align... but how? You have a two possible axis and a large number of scenarios that one would consider as an alignment. How do you want to arrange these images: At baseline? Vertically centered? Horizontally centered? Space in between? It will be very useful to include some illustration to show us what you intend to achieve. Also, including a minimal, concrete and verifiable example can help a lot.

Comment: @Terry I'm trying to have them side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try ... to read ... your mind ...
and think you need:
a bit of ccs:

```
    div.gallery {display: inline-block; }
```

and
a bit of html:

```
    <center><div class="gallery"><img ..> <p ..>..</p></div>
```

for all 3 or 4 or 5 and a

```
    <br>
```

for a new line. At last a

```
    </center>
```

to close it.

Et voila: one layout of millions you could do/use.
Or you listen to the spice girls and you can "tell me what you want, what you really really want..." ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves a lot of room for interpretation (and guessing), but for images with captions you should use the `figure` tag, with `img` and `figcaption` tags inside it, and apply CSS as desired. I suppose you want something like this:

```css
figure {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="Images/LoadingE.png">
  <figcaption>
    We have an animated loading screen!
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="Images/GameE.png">
  <figcaption>
    We have an interactive main menu!
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="Images/player.png">
  <figcaption>

    This is our amazing player!
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
```

Comment: My current code already does this. I need the images side by side.

Comment: well, you should have written that in the question. "aligning" can mean horizonzally or vertically. With 40% width one tends to think it should be vertically, since 3 x 40 extends the width...